# How can I decide removing the libarm.so shared library from vitamio player

Tags: android, vitamio

Similar question has been asked here [What is libarm.so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559674/what-is-libarm-so) but mine is more specific.

I am using the vitamio project to stream a video using rtmp protocol but the libarm.so (8.8 MB size) is ***making app very large***.

So I want to delete the libarm.so shared lib but am not sure about its consequences.

*Can someone help me list the list of file formats and protocols that need this shared lib*?.

Thanks,

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: No , I did not. upvote if you want it to be more popular ;)